# How to write the seats for a booking application in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using right now this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="40" Width="50" Margin="4,4,4,4"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

With this:

```
        <ItemsControl 
            x:Name="lst" 
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TopSeats}"/>
```

I'm binding a List< List< int?>> as itemssource with numbers 0-2. 0 for empty, 1 for selected, 2 for booked.

```
    List<List<int?>> topSeats;

    public List<List<int?>> TopSeats
    {
        get => topSeats;
        set
        {
            topSeats = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TopSeats");
        }
    }
```

My UI looks like this right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaFPg.png)

When i press a button, it should change from 0 to 1, and the corresponding element in the List< List< int?>> container should change too.
But i've arrived to a brick wall. I have no idea how to make sure that, when i press any button, the correct element changes in the "List< List< int?>>" container.

Is it possible somehow without code behind?

Comment: please post minimal reproducible code to resolve your issue.

Comment: There is no more code for this, i got a list, im binding it, that's all. It works.
I want that when i click on a button, that the corresponding cell in my 2 dimensional list changes. No code for this, because i have no idea on how to do it, that's why i asked. I don't need exact solution, i'm even happy if you give me hints on what should i look for.

Answer (score 2):

Its a big process to explain everything here. But I'll try my best to give you a working solution and hope you can read more about INotifyPropertyChanged, MVVM pattern and ICommand pattern.

For simplicity, I have not implemented ICommand here and using a code-behind click to get the selected seat numbers (This is only for testing to see if selected seat numbers are able to retrieve or not).

**Step 1:** I have created a Model class called Seat with following properties and I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface to capture property changed events. See below for my Seat.cs class.

```
public class Seat : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int seatNo;
        private string seatNumber;
        private bool isSelected;

        public int SeatNo
        {
            get { return seatNo; }
            set { seatNo = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public string SeatNumber
        {
            get { return seatNumber; }
            set { seatNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set { isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string popertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(popertyName));
        }

        private void BaseVM_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**Step 2:**
I have modified **"DataTemplate_Level2"** template to have a CheckBox instead of a Button. Because I wanted to get the selected behavior where CheckBox has it. See below for the modified **"DataTemplate_Level2"**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2" DataType="{x:Type local:Seat}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding SeatNumber}" Height="40" Width="50" Margin="4" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Step 3:** I have modified appearance of the CheckBox. So that it does not appear like a checkbox but looks like a button (you can still customize to look like a real seat). See below for my modified CheckBoxStyle

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}, Path=Content}"
                                       TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**Step 4:** I have added some buttons and textblock to my Window to test for the selected seats (This piece of code is for testing purpose only). See below my rest of the xaml.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" ItemsSource="{Binding TopSeatList}"/>

        <Button Content="Get Selected Seat Numbers" Height="40" Width="50" Margin="4,4,4,4" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="SelectedSeatNumbersTextBlock" Grid.Row="2" />

    </Grid>
```

**Note:-** There is no modification for **"DataTemplate_Level1"**. Hence you can still copy-paste of yours.

**Step 5:** Now in my main window view model, I have added a list like your **List< List >** and populated some dummy data.

```
      public List<List<Seat>> TopSeatList
        {
            get => topSeatList;
            set
            {
                topSeatList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TopSeatList");
            }
        }
```

**Step 6:** In the code-behind for the Button_Click event I did to get the selected seat numbers and display in a textblock.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedSeats = selectSeatsViewModel.TopSeatList.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.IsSelected));
            string selectedSeatNumbers = string.Empty;
            foreach(var seat in selectedSeats)
            {
                selectedSeatNumbers += seat.SeatNumber + "";
            }

            SelectedSeatNumbersTextBlock.Text = selectedSeatNumbers;
        }
```

**Note:-** I consider to implement much better approach above click event with a command so that you can avoid it writing it in code-behind.

I hope this helps you to move forward with your solution. Please give a try and let us know results. Feel free to post your questions.